# how to import external class in Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Im trying to import a not shared library class to a shared library class and gets an error:

**file structure**

```groovy
.
├── src
│   └── org
│       └── jenkins
│            └──shared_library.groovy
│            └──not_shared_library.groovy
│
│── jenkinsfile.groovy
```

**not_shared_library calss**

```groovy
package src.org.jenkins 

class not_shared_library {
private name

not_shared_library(name) {
 this.name = name
}

def some_func(){
  return this.name+"is not_shared_library_obj"
}
```

**shared_library calss**

```groovy
package src.org.jenkins
import  src.org.jenkins.not_shared_library 

class shared_library implements Serializable {
private steps

shared_library(steps) {
    this.steps = steps
}
def not_shared_lib = new not_shared_library("not_shared_lib")

def get_not_shared_library(){
     print not_shared_lib.some_func()
}
```

**jenkinsfile**

```groovy
@Library 'shared_library'
import org.jenkins.shared_library

my_shared_library = new shared_library(steps)

node(){
  stage('my_first_stage'){
    my_shared_library.get_not_shared_library()
}
```

/jenkins_data/jobs/main_DEV/builds/51/libs/global_utils/src/org/jenkins/shared_library.groovy: 8: 
    unable to resolve class src.org.jenkins.not_shared_library @ line 8, column 1.  import src.org.jenkins.not_shared_library @ line 116, column 21. not_shared_lib
    = new not_shared_library("not_shared_lib")       ^